# How can you extend behavior of the spring boot autoconfiguration?

Tags: spring-boot

I am looking to extend JacksonAutoConfiguration specifically when the builder is created, i would like to set that ObjectMapper to a Util class which has static setter for the ObjectMapper. Look at the line before returning builder where I would like to set ObjectMpper to a static class.

```
@Bean
        @ConditionalOnMissingBean(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.class)
        public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonObjectMapperBuilder() {
            Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
            builder.applicationContext(this.applicationContext);
            if (this.jacksonProperties.getSerializationInclusion() != null) {
                builder.serializationInclusion(this.jacksonProperties
                        .getSerializationInclusion());
            }
            configureFeatures(builder, this.jacksonProperties.getDeserialization());
            configureFeatures(builder, this.jacksonProperties.getSerialization());
            configureFeatures(builder, this.jacksonProperties.getMapper());
            configureFeatures(builder, this.jacksonProperties.getParser());
            configureFeatures(builder, this.jacksonProperties.getGenerator());
            configureDateFormat(builder);
            configurePropertyNamingStrategy(builder);
            configureModules(builder);
            **ObjectMapperUtils.setObjectMapper( builder.build() );**
            return builder;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ObjectMapper` created from the auto-configured `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` is exposed as a bean in the `JacksonAutoConfiguration`. You could simply create another `@Configuration` class, get a reference to the `ObjectMapper` (via auto-wiring) and use an `@PostConstruct` method to set the `ObjectMapper` in your `ObjectMapperUtils` class.

Another suggestion would be to refactor `ObjectMapperUtils` so that it is created as a Spring bean itself, then you can auto-wire `ObjectMapper` directly into it.

Comment: thanks for the response, I would like this to setup before the other Beans gets initialized. I tried @AutoConfigureBefore( JacksonAutoConfigure.class, JacksonCustomConfigure.class ) however JacksonCustomConfigure doesnt seem to be getting called

Comment: Is `JacksonCustomConfigure` an auto-configured class (in the spring.factories file?)

Comment: Is it the only class i need to add ? or I need to copy the spring.factories from spring boot and all other auto configuration classes?

Comment: Any class that you want to be an auto-configuration candidate needs to be in a spring.factories file in a META-INF folder on the classpath. See [Developing auto-configuration and using conditions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-developing-auto-configuration) in the reference documentation.

Comment: Ok, however I would like @PostConstruct method to be called before other beans are initialized, issue is i have few other bean which is using ObjectMapperUtils static methods from their PostConstruct method to deserialize json, however PostConstruct method seems to be getting called in the end. The behavior i want is as soon as JackonAutoConfigure is configured i would like this custom configuration to set the ObjectMapper to ObjectMapperUtils.

Comment: actually that works, this is what I ended up doing in @AutoconfigureBefore i added JacksonAutoConfigure and JacksonCustomConfigure classes, i autowired ObjectMapper in JacksonCustomConfigure class and in PostConstruct method I set ObjectMapperUtils.setObjectMapper( mapper) and also added JacksonCustomConfigure in spring.factories ( very important ) my only question is by overriding spring.factories will it override default default auto configure behavior ? i.e will spring boot still auto configure other classes from default spring.factories?

Comment: Spring Boot will still auto-configure other class from spring.factories. Any jar on the classpath that has a META-INF/spring.factories file with auto-configuration candidates listed will be considered.